# Posting values entered in a sign up form to an SQLite database and printing out the values in console

Tags: python, list, sqlite, tkinter

Good Day,
I created a sign-up form in Python with Tkinter and I want to push the values entered into an SQLite database. I also want to print out these values in console in form of a list. However when I ran my code I got an error. This is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jun  1 09:10:44 2021

@author: Anjolaoluwa

User Interface to create User Account
"""
from tkinter import *
# from tkinter import messagebox  #import to show an alert
import re  #regular expression
import sqlite3


class Application (Frame):
    def __init__(self, anjie):
        super(Application, self).__init__(anjie)
        # getting the init() function in frame
        self.conn=self.sqlite3.connect("signupdb.db")
        self.cursor=self.conn.cursor()
        sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS signup(password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, email VARCHAR(100), username VARCHAR(100))"
        self.grid()  # allows grid function to work
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        menubar = Menu(self)  # create the menubar in menu

        filemenu = Menu(menubar)  # create a menu item in menubar
        # add file menu item that has a drop down in menubar
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

        # adding values as drop downs in menu item file
        filemenu.add_command(label="New")
        # adding values as drop downs in menu item file
        filemenu.add_command(label="Open")
        # adding values as drop downs in menu item file
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save")
        # adding values as drop downs in menu item file
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save as")

        # add quit menu item that has no drop down in menubar
        menubar.add_command(label="Quit", command=window.quit)

        # Entering our form fields
        self.email_label = Label(self, text="Email")
        self.email_label.pack()

        self.email = Entry(self, width=25)
        self.email.pack()

        self.username_label = Label(self, text="Name")
        self.username_label.pack()

        self.username = Entry(self, width=25)
        self.username.pack()

        self.password_label = Label(self, text="Password")
        self.password_label.pack()

        self.password = Entry(self, width=25, show="*")
        self.password.pack()

        self.confirm_label = Label(self, text="Confirm Password")
        self.confirm_label.pack()

        self.confirm = Entry(self, width=25, show="*")
        self.confirm.pack()

        self.space = Label(self, text="")
        self.space.pack()

        # bracket after validate runs the function already on start so I removed it
        self.submit = Button(self, text="Sign Up", fg="white",
                             bg="blue", width=20, command=self.validate)
        self.submit.pack()

        window.config(menu=menubar)

    def validate(self):
        submitOk = True

        # getting the values put in the labels
        email = self.email.get()
        username = self.username.get()
        password = self.password.get()
        confirm = self.confirm.get()

        email_pattern = '\\w+@{1}\\w+\\S'
        email_result = re.match(email_pattern, email)
        if not email_result:  # if email_result is false
            submitOk = False
            # title of the messagebox is error while the content/message is Invalid email
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Invalid email")

        username_pattern = "\\w{4,}\\S"
        username_result = re.match(username_pattern, username)
        if not username_result:
            submitOk = False
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Invalid username")

        if submitOk is False:
            return False
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", "User Registered Successfully")
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO signup (password,email,username)" "VALUES (password,email,username)")
            allrows=[]
            for row in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM signup"):
                allrows.append(row)
            print(allrows)
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()

window = Tk()
window.title("Menu Bar")
window.geometry("800x500")  # WIDTH BY HEIGHT
app = Application(window)
app.mainloop()
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ariel\OneDrive\Documents\400L\SIWES\NH PYTHON\newpython\usersignup.py", line 121, in validate
    self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO signup (password,email,username)" "VALUES (password,email,username)")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: signup
```

Please how do I resolve the error? I would appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: You just create the `sql = "CREATE TABLE ..."`, but never execute it.  So the table will not be created.

Comment: I have added the line ```self.cursor.execute(sql)``` but I get this new error ```Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ariel\OneDrive\Documents\400L\SIWES\NH PYTHON\newpython\usersignup.py", line 108, in validate
    self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO signup (password,email,username)" "VALUES (password,email,username)")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: password```

Comment: Check your INSERT statement, it is invalid.  Also there are typos in your code.

Comment: Also your table design is strange.  Why `password` is the primary key? It should be `username` instead.

Comment: What typos please? And how is my INSERT statement invalid?

Comment: never mind I've been able to correct the code. Thank you

Comment: you neednt that part in your class: ` sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS signup(password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, email VARCHAR(100), username VARCHAR(100)` . you can do it in a function, if you need it. so you have an instant call, when you run your application

Comment: [SQLite Python: Inserting Data](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/insert/)